# Download large file on Google App Engine Python

Tags: file, google-app-engine, csv, download, google-app-engine-python

On my appspot website, I use a third party API to query a large amount of data. The user then downloads the data in CSV. I know how to generate a csv and download it. The problem is that because the file is huge, I get the DeadlineExceededError.

I have tried tried increasing the fetch deadline to 60 (urlfetch.set_default_fetch_deadline(60)). It doesn't seem reasonable to increase it any further.

What is the appropriate way to tackle this problem on Google App Engine? Is this something where I have to use Task Queue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DeadlineExceededError means that your incoming request took longer than 60 secs, not your UrlFetch call.

Deploy the code to generate the CSV file into a different module that you setup with [basic or manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class). The URL to download your CSV will become http://module.domain.com

Requests can run indefinitely on modules with basic or manual scaling.

Comment: I tried your method. I have few questions. One is that when I deploy a manually scaling module, Google App Engine detects it as a backend instance. Isn't backend going to be fully deprecated soon? Also, I can't seem to route requests to the new/different module. Any guidance on this? I followed the tutorial here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Comment: @andy7586 how do you tell that GAE detects this as backend ? That should not happen, unless - maybe - that you need to migrate to modules first, you can do this from the old appengine.google.com console under "Application Settings"

Comment: I know that it detects it as a backend because it uses the backend instance hours. Also, what do I do under "Application Settings"? Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Not convinced that really means it detects it as backends, might be because you setup the instance as B0-8 types. Do you have a dropdown to select the module in the "instances" section ? If you are still using frontends/backends then in "Application Settings" you'd find migration instructions, otherwise you are using modules.

Comment: I do see the other module version in the new developer's console. But when I map the url dispatch, I am not able to access the web page that I want. I am attaching my code in the section below

Comment: @andy7586 would be nice to accept the answer if it solves your problem. yw.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, consider creating a file dynamically in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) with your CSV content. At that point, the file resides in GCS and you have the ability to generate a URL from which they can download the file directly. There are also other options for different auth methods.

You can see documentation on doing this at

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

and

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/functions

Important note: do not use the Files API (which was a common way of dynamically create files in blobstore/gcs) as it has been depracated. Use the above referenced Google Cloud Storage Client API instead.

Of course, you can delete the generated files after they've been successfully downloaded and/or you could run a cron job to expire links/files after a certain time period.

Depending on your specific use case, this might be a more effective path.